# What is the most scalable and efficient way to build out a GUI in perl?

Tags: perl, user-interface

S.O. Community,

I am looking to experiment with some application based projects with perl and was wondering, what is the best way to build a GUI in perl? The purpose of this would be to fill the entire screen. The application would most likely run on startup of the machine, so it would almost be like a kiosk (in the sense where there are no borders to the window). I do not want this to be web based where I direct to a local or public IP, rather it would be an installable program.

Thank you for the help!

-DJohn

Comment: Have a look at [Tk](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Tk/Tk.pod) or [Gtk3](https://metacpan.org/pod/Gtk3)

Comment: Perl is not really known (anymore) for a good support of GUI toolkits. It might be better to reevaluate your restrictions regarding programming language and/or web based or not.

Comment: I was between Perl and Python quite honestly. What would you recommend? I am at the most ground part of this project, so I would be happy to learn a new skill if you have a suggestion.

Comment: @DJohn: if you have the choice and really need a graphical toolkit instead of web then use Python since it has much better [support for graphical toolkits](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming). Still, your question is too unfocused since there is no best for all toolkit or way to go. It really depends on what you want to achieve, how it should look, what platforms you need to address etc. Note also that an application can use web technology and still be "installable" - whatever this exactly means.

Comment: Thank you, this will not be graphic intensive (I hope). More so just a display to show off some features such as weather, time, news, etc. Will not be much at first.

Comment: If you decided to use Perl as the language then there is definitely good support for GUI. I'd recommend `Gtk3`, but `wxWidgets` is a highly reputable toolkit as well.  Many of the graphical environments to use for work (if you aren't up for the simple console work) are available as well, like Komodo, MS's "code", glade, etc.

Comment: I don't really understand the statement that Perl lacks support for GUI toolkits? I've written GUI's with it and had no problems whatsoever.  If your language is Perl then just go ahead and write a GUI -- that's not a reason to change languages!  (However, if the language choice is open for you then by all means choose, and the suggested Python is great to work with of course.)

Comment: Forgot to mention, `qt` is also available of course; see [PerlQt](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/PerlQt/PerlQt/Qt.pod) with its [tutorial](http://perlqt.sourceforge.net/dist/current/doc/en/index.html) (I also find [this site](http://perlqt.wikidot.com/) for it). It's normally a good idea to use the toolkit native to your desktop environment, so that your applications have a native look -- in Gnome it's `Gtk3`, in KDE it's `qt`.

Comment: Thank you guys for the support. I only suggested perl because it I had the dependencies installed on my linux box. Needlesss to say, its easy to migrate to Git. This is more of a learning experience for an associate and I. I will explore the perl and python paths to see what I prefer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a full screen window without borders using [Gtk3](https://metacpan.org/pod/Gtk3)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Gtk3 -init;
use Glib 'TRUE', 'FALSE';

my $window = Gtk3::Window->new( 'toplevel' );
$window->signal_connect( destroy  => sub { Gtk3->main_quit() } );
my $label = Gtk3::Label->new('Hello world!');
$label->set_hexpand(TRUE);
my $grid = Gtk3::Grid->new();
$window->add( $grid );
$grid->attach($label, 0,0,1,1);
my $button = Gtk3::Button->new();
$button->set_label('Exit');
$button->signal_connect('clicked' => sub {  Gtk3->main_quit() } );
$grid->attach($button, 0,1,1,1);
#$window->set_default_size( 200, 200 );
$window->set_position('center_always');
$window->show_all();
$window->set_decorated(FALSE);
#$window->set_keep_above(TRUE);
$window->fullscreen();
$window->show_all();
Gtk3->main();
```